# Orchard cms is not run when change permission in root folder of Plesk hosting

Tags: permissions, orchardcms, plesk

I deploy orchard cms to Plesk hosting

My site is running perfectly in Plesk Hosting

I go to Home > domains > (my domain) > Virtual Directories > Directory Properties

Currently I allow Write permission and Scripts and Executables

When I Un-check "Write Permission" and "Scripts and Executables" 
=> It show "This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed" in Chrome and "The website declined to show this webpage" in IE9

I check "Write Permission" and "Scripts and Executables"  again, website is still does not work

Please show me how to debug, Please save me!

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a super-easy solution to this problem: do not remove write permissions. They are needed. As to why re-checking those boxes didn't restore the site, you should talk to your hosting company, that seems like a problem on their side. You may want to restart the appdomain, see if it makes a difference.
If you want finer-grained control over what requires write permissions, app_data, modules, themes and media require it.

Comment: thanks, I have to re-install Orchard CMS. Then I install in Plesk use following guide: http://orchardcms.co.za/articles/configuring-orchard-on-plesk-hosting. I worked!